# C# Suppress nullable after custom thrower method, like ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull

Tags: c#, exception, nullable

I'm trying to create similar functionality to that of the [`ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9e5d843c96634b619a22d318594a90dbd463802f/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/ArgumentNullException.cs#L59) method, in that the compiler should know that when the input argument is null, any code executed after the call to this function does not need to worry about possible null reference.

I've more of less copied the `ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull` code from the link above, but I'm still getting the old *"Dereference of a possibly null reference."* warning.

Here's what I have:

```cs
public class MyExeption : Exception
{
    public static void ThrowIfNull(object? thing)
    {
        if (thing is null) Throw();
    }

    [DoesNotReturn]
    public static void Throw() => throw new MyExeption();
}
```

And the usage:

```cs
object? obj = null;
MyExeption.ThrowIfNull(obj);

var str = obj.ToString(); // <- Dereference of a possibly null reference
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you notice the `[NotNull]` attribute on `argument` in the code you linked?

Comment: Doh! I actually did spot this and stupidly instantly dismissed it as I thought I knew that this was for something else. But yes, this was exactly what I was missing. Thank you!